# Раскрытие меню при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите почему не раскрывается подменю при наведении

```js
$(".leftmenu > li").hover(
  function(){
    var a = $(this).find("ul.sub_level");
    a.toggle();
    console.log(a);
  })
```

```css
    ul.sub_level li {
        display: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: #714636;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="leftmenu">
 <li><a href="">Раздел 1</a>
  <ul class="sub_level">
   <li><a href="/service/antimonopolnoe_regulirovanie.htm">Текст1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/kommercheskoe_pravo.htm">Текст2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/nalogooblozhenie.htm">Текст3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="">Раздел 2</a>
  <ul class="sub_level">
   <li><a href="/service/antimonopolnoe_regulirovanie.htm">Текст1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/kommercheskoe_pravo.htm">Текст2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/nalogooblozhenie.htm">Текст3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".leftmenu > li").hover(
  function(){
    var a = $(this).find("ul.sub_level");
    a.toggle();
  })
```

```css
.sub_level {
        display: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: #714636;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="leftmenu">
 <li><a href="">Раздел 1</a>
  <ul class="sub_level">
   <li><a href="/service/antimonopolnoe_regulirovanie.htm">Текст1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/kommercheskoe_pravo.htm">Текст2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/nalogooblozhenie.htm">Текст3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="">Раздел 2</a>
  <ul class="sub_level">
   <li><a href="/service/antimonopolnoe_regulirovanie.htm">Текст1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/kommercheskoe_pravo.htm">Текст2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/service/nalogooblozhenie.htm">Текст3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2tb8w2o/1/)
Убрал li в вашем стиле и при наведении стал появляться список.

```
ul.sub_level {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #714636;
}
```